# Perl match multiple strings on same line (anything inside double and single quotes)

Tags: regex, perl

I thought this should be simple, matching strings in double/single quotes on same line

for example, following string all on same line

`"hello" 'world' 'foo' "bar"`

I have
`print /(".*?")|('.*?')/g;`

but I got following errors

`Use of uninitialized value in print at ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will return the warnings you mention:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = q{"hello" 'world' 'foo' "bar"};

print $str =~ /(".*?")|('.*?')/g;
```

That is because your regex will only match either one or the other of capture groups.  The other one will not match and so will return `undef`.

The following will demonstrate:

```
while ($str =~ /(".*?")|('.*?')/g) {
    print "one = " . (defined $1 ? $1 : 'undef') . "\n";
    print "two = " . (defined $2 ? $2 : 'undef') . "\n";
    print "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
one = "hello"
two = undef

one = undef
two = 'world'

one = undef
two = 'foo'

one = "bar"
two = undef
```

To get your desired behavior, just put the capture group around the entire expression.

```
print $str =~ /(".*?"|'.*?')/g;
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check [Text::ParseWords](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html)

```
use Text::ParseWords;

my $s = q{"hello" 'world' 'foo' "bar"};
my @words = quotewords('\s+', 0, $s);

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@words;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = [
      'hello',
      'world',
      'foo',
      'bar'
    ];
```

Answer (score -1):

anoher option using backreference:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = q{"hello" 'world' 'foo' "bar"};

while ($str =~ /(["']).*?\1/g) {
    print  $&  . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Don't use `$&`, instead put the whole regex into a capture group. Usage of `$&` will slow down all regex matches in the whole program.